# Event to check all flux events are loaded in current page - Flux, React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, flux

I need to trigger an event, to check if all the event loading are complete in the current page / current route.

For suppose

```
Current route is `/address`
```

The events which are loaded in this routes are

```
LOAD_NAME
LOAD_PHONE_NUMBER
LOAD_GOOGLE_LOCATION
```

So here `LOAD_GOOGLE_LOCATION` will take its time to execute. I need to trigger another `Event` after all these event loading are complete

I'm using `React` and `Flux`

Answer (score 0):

If you are using [redux-thunk](https://github.com/reduxjs/redux-thunk), you can implement your actions like that:

```
const loadName = url => dispatch => fetch(url)
  .then(res => res.json())
  .then(json => {
    dispatch({ type: 'LOAD_NAME', data: json  }
    return json;
  }))


const loadPhoneNumber = url => dispatch => fetch(url)
  .then(res => res.json())
  .then(json => {
    dispatch({ type: 'LOAD_PHONE_NUMBER', data: json  };
    return json;
  }))


const loadGoggleLocation = url => dispatch => fetch(url)
  .then(res => res.json())
  .then(json => {
    dispatch({ type: 'LOAD_GOOGLE_LOCATION', data: json  };
    return json;
   }))

//load one after the other
const loadAll = () => dispatch => 
  loadName(…)
    .then(json => loadPhoneNumber(json.number))
    .then(json => loadGoogleLocation(json.location))
    .then(dispatch({ type: 'ALL_LOAD' }))

//load all in parallel
const loadAll = () => dispatch => Promise.all([
  loadName(…),
  loadPhoneNumber(…),
  loadGoggleLocation(…)
])
  .then(([namejson, numberjson, locationjson]) => 
     dispatch({ type: 'ALL_LOAD' }))
```

This way:

- your actions can still be used »standalone«
- your state gets updated as data arrives,
- you do not need to check the state for existing data/flags to make sure all dependencies are met
- you can easily extend this to much more dependencies